# copy from beginning up to the last occurrence found

Tags: c, arrays, char

How can I copy from beginning up to the last occurrence found?

```
strncpy(name,long_name,strrchr(long_name,'.')+1);
```

Comment: What do you want to do if there's no occurrence of `'.'` in the string to begin with?

Comment: I run strrchr first, check for null, and if so strcpy(name,"")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strrchr()` returns a pointer to the last occurance. Subtract the pointer to the start of the string from that and you have the length.

```
strncpy(name,long_name, strrchr(long_name,'.') - long_name);
```

However, this does *not* null terminate `name` automatically. Make sure you've initialized it to all `\0` first.  Also note that `strrchr()` returns `NULL` if the character doesn't exist. You probably want to move it outside of the `strncpy()` and check to make sure you have a valid pointer first.

```
char *last = strrchr(long_name,'.');
if (last != NULL)
    strncpy(name,long_name, last - long_name);
```

**Edit:** I'm assuming you typo'd the variable name in `strrchr()` in your post - it should be `long_name`

Comment: Thank you, I originally implemented a check for null before I attempted to strcpy. This answer works just like I was hoping. But the first iteration the variable is correct, the next it is wrong with a little garbage, the next even more garbage, and so on. Working to fix that now. Thanks again everyone

Comment: Apologies for needing this baby fed, but to initialize to zero, would memcpy be my guy?

Comment: Use `memset()` to set `name` to all `\0` each time before you copy into it. Option B would be to null terminate manually after each `strncpy` with `*(name + (last - long_name)) = '\0';`

Comment: If you know, as in this case, that the `n` you are passing is less than or equal to `strlen(src)`, then there is no point calling `strncpy()`.  Instead you should simply use `memcpy(name, long_name, last - long_name); name[last - long_name] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need one temporary to check for validity, and another to account for the length of `name`:

```
char name[N] = { };

const char * const p = strrchar(long_name, '.');
unsigned int const n = p - long_name;
strncpy(name, long_name, p ? (n < N ? n : N) : 0);
```

Alternatively, you can allocate the memory for `name` *dynamically* after you know how long it should be: `char * name = malloc(n + 1); name[n] = 0;`.